# jquery hoverintent help to integrate

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-hover

I have the following problem ...

I find myself in a structure like this:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="one column" id="menu1" style="height:75px; padding-top:35px;"><a href="#">TEXT MENU 1</a></div>
                <div class="three columns" id="menu2" style="height:75px; padding-top:35px;"><a href="#">TEXT MENU 2</a></div>
                <div class="one column" id="menu3" style="height:75px; padding-top:35px;"><a href="#">TEXT MENU 3</a></div>
            </div><div style="position:fixed; display:none; top:125px; width:100%; background-color:#03F;" id="down1">     
      <div class="row">        
        <div class="twelve columns" style="padding-top:18px;">
          <ul>
            <li style="width:30%;"><a href="#">TEXT 1</a></li>
            <li style="width:30%"><a href="#">TEXT 2</a></li>
            <li style="width:30%"><a href="#">TEXT 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>      
  </div>
```

this is the menu with the dropdown that I should slow down to allow the user to go from left to right without activating the hover button next to it.

Jquery code :

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#menu1").mouseover(function(){
          $("#sotto1").stop().slideDown("slow");
          $("#sotto2").slideUp("slow");
          $("#sotto3").slideUp("slow");
      });

)};
</script>
```

Now I would like to integrate jQuery hoverIntent in this structure I can recommend how to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       var menu_config = {
           over: show,
           timeout: 250,
           out: hide    
       };
       function show() {
       $("#sotto1").stop().slideDown("slow");
           $("#sotto2").slideUp("slow");
           $("#sotto3").slideUp("slow");
       }
       function hide() {
       $("#sotto1").stop().slideUp("slow");
           $("#sotto2").slideDown("slow");
           $("#sotto3").slideDown("slow");
       }
       $("#menu1").hoverIntent(menu_config);

   )};
</script>
```